# javascript fullcalendar plus bootstrap tooltips

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I am trying to attach a bootstrap tooltip to a particular fullcalendar day-view `td` element. I can get the `td` element from the FC click event on that element.  If I do a `console.dir(thing);` then the element comes back as an object that (in chrome's js console) looks like:

```
i.fn.init(1)
    # 0: td.ui-widget-content
      length: 1
    # __proto__: Object(0)
```

The `#`s imply sub-objects.  Ok, what I want is the "text" value of that "0" object key... I want to get the string "td.ui-widget-content".

I've tried the following:

```
console.dir(thing);
console.dir(thing[0]);
console.log(Object.keys(thing));
console.log(Object.keys(thing[0]));
```

The first yeilds the object above.  The second prints

```
# td.ui-widget-content
```

Again, the `#` implies a sub-object. The third prints

```
# (2) ["0", "length"]
```

and the last prints

```
# []
```

If I do `console.log(thing[0])` the reault is the outter html of the DOM element.

How do I get that "td.ui-widget-content" string from the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` will be a jquery object during the "dayClick" event.

Bootstrap tooltips, as I understand them from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/ can be attached to jQuery objects.

Therefore

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
  this.tooltip({ title: "Hi" });
}
```

should do what you need, I think.